# Can I say ‘each represented a goddess’?

Tags: word-usage

I saw the sentence in my book **‘each one represented a goddess’**, and I felt I can delete the ‘one’ of the sentence. Can I, and why?

Comment: If you look at some dictionary definitions of ***each***, I'm sure you'll find that most of them mention the specific word pair ***every one*** as a possible replacement. So maybe we could say ***one*** is "optional" because it's already implicit in ***each*** anyway. You haven't given a full context for your fragment (it's not even a complete *sentence*, if I take account of the fact it doesn't start with a capital letter), but I will just point out that idiomatically today you *can't* include ***one*** in contexts like *We found several statues that **each represented a goddess**.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Each one represented a goddess. Can this sentence have ‘one’?

Comment: Probably. But it would help if you would provide more context ***in the question text above***. For example a link to your source, or at least you could tell us what words / sentences came *before* the words you've given us. At the moment it's not at all clear, and including a capital letter in the *comment* version (but not in the question text itself) just makes things even more vague.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It could well be that the lower-case "each" is found in the original. I only found [two hits](https://www.google.com/search?q="each+one+represented+a+goddess") for this phrase on Google, and neither one had "Each". It appears to be an English translation of a Chinese text. Your point is a good one, though, and the OP should realize: the less you tell us about a sentence, the less we can tell you about that sentence.

Comment: @J.R.: I did actually check Google *Books* for the specific text, but it wasn't found. I never thought to check Google *Internet*, but I see now that you're right about there being only two instances. FWIW, my gut feel is that including unnecessary / optional ***one*** in such contexts is a kind of "emphasizer". I don't have the necessary technical skills to confirm my thinking by a corpus search, but my feeling is that "more emphatic" version is more likely if preceding text states or implies ***quite a few, more than you might expect*** examples of whatever kind of thing we're talking about.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The original sentence is:' According to our guidebook, fragments of a number of statues were found, and each one represented a goddess.'      But I saw this sentence in another book:' Each of these represented a goddess.'  So I am curious about when I should use 'each' and when I should use 'each one'.

Comment: Per my first comment, ***each*** is effectively synonymous with ***every one***. That's to say it's fine to revise your example context to ***Every one** of these represented a goddess* - but regardless of whether or not the "original" included the word ***one***, it *must* be present if we use ***every*** rather than ***each***. But I can't think of any context where it's *necessary* to include ***one*** after ***each***, so I think if you want something easy to learn that will never lead to you making mistakes, just choose between either plain ***each*** or (more emphatic) ***every one***.

Answer (score 2):

I think in *all* such contexts, *each **one*** is simply an optional "flourish" that doesn't really make any difference at all - but some people might think it adds slightly more emphasis.

Most dictionaries would probably give ***every one*** (two words, not the single-word form ***everyone = everybody = all people***) as an exact synonym that can directly replace ***each***. But note that regardless of whether or not the "original" included the word ***one***, it's always required after ***every*** in such contexts.

I can't think of any context where it's *necessary* to include ***one*** after ***each***, so my advice for learners would be to stick with plain ***each*** unless you want to be more emphatic, in which case you could express that using ***every [single] one*** (where including ***single*** adds even more emphasis, but note that ***each single one*** would rarely be idiomatic).